# Sarg is not properly generating separate reports per day

Tags: logging, report, squid

I use Sarg to generate reports for squid, but is not working properly.

Configuration: Default

The log period should be daily, but it is always creating from the first day.

Dec24-2018-Dec31

The correct date is:
Dec30-2018-Dec31 
Dec29-2018-Dec30
Dec28-2018-Dec29
...
...
...

[image: SARG]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked again without me doing anything. Probably the problem was the log generated by squid.